# How to fix NotSerializableException error during Jenkins workflow build?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-build-flow

When I run the following code on the Jenkins workflow (Jenkins 1.609.1 ,workflow 1.8)  I get error of 'NotSerializableException' (also below).
However, if I move the "build job" outside the "for" scope it works fine (the job is activated). Any ideas why this behavior?

```
node('master') { 
ws('/opt/test) {
def file = "/ot.property"
def line = readFile (file)
def resultList = line.tokenize()
for(item in resultList )
  {
build job: 'testjob_1'
   }
 }
}
```

Got error:

```
Running: End of Workflow 
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.ArrayList$Itr  
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:860)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)  


.....
```

Comment: For me I found the best and simplest workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40166064/1929406

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I thnk it is because it's trying to serialize the unserializable `item` iterator on `resultList` as soon as it hits the `build job` step. See here for guidance on use of nonserializable variables:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#serialization-of-local-variables

As a workaround to safely iterate using the workflow plugin, you need to us C-style loops. Try this instead:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < resultList.size; i++ ) {
  etc...
```

Comment: Further reference here:

<https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jenkinsci-users/LGRv7Jq60YI/ZN-68zuw2loJ>

Comment: tnx, seems better now!

Comment: FYI, this particular error is tracked as [JENKINS-27421](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27421).

Comment: But how can I do the same for maps?

Answer (score 8):

According to [CloudBees Platform Help page](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/204972960-The-pipeline-even-if-successful-ends-with-java-io-NotSerializableException):

> By design the pipeline can only keep records of `Serializable` objects. If you still need to keep an intermediate variable with a non serializable object, you need to hide it into a method and annotate this method with `@NonCPS`.

So you should transform your code into a function with `@NonCPS` helper method.

Related Jenkins bug: [JENKINS-27421](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27421).

Comment: Yep. found this beautiful example to that effect: https://gist.github.com/oifland/ab56226d5f0375103141b5fbd7807398

Comment: Important thing to keep in mind here: you can't execute pipeline steps from an @NonCPS method! https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/VXrSVBZ2maU