# Impossibility to iterate over a Map using Groovy within Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: dictionary, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

We are trying to iterate over a `Map`, but without any success. We reduced our issue to this minimal example:

```
def map = [
           'monday': 'mon',
           'tuesday': 'tue',
           ]
```

If we try to iterate with:

```
map.each{ k, v -> println "${k}:${v}" }
```

Only the first entry is output: `monday:mon`

---

The alternatives we know of are not even able to enter the loop:

```
for (e in map)
{
    println "key = ${e.key}, value = ${e.value}"
}
```

or

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> e: map.entrySet())
{
    println "key = ${e.key}, value = ${e.value}"
}
```

Are failing, both only showing the exception `java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry`. (which could be related to an exception occurring while raising the 'real' exception, preventing us from knowing what happened).

We are using latest stable jenkins (2.19.1) with all plugins up-to-date as of today (2016/10/20).

Is there a solution to iterate over elements in a `Map` within a Jenkins pipeline Groovy script ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Its been some time since I played with this, but the best way to iterate through maps (and other containers) was with "classical" for loops, or the "for in". See [Bug: Mishandling of binary methods accepting Closure](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26481)

To your specific problem, most (all?) pipeline DSL commands will add a sequence point, with that I mean its possible to save the state of the pipeline and resume it at a later time. Think of waiting for user input for example, you want to keep this state even through a restart.
The result is that every live instance has to be serialized - but the standard Map iterator is unfortunately not serializable. [Original Thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/oDBhrVxUeeM)

The best solution I can come up with is defining a Function to convert a Map into a list of serializable MapEntries. The function is not using any pipeline steps, so nothing has to be serializable within it.

```groovy
@NonCPS
def mapToList(depmap) {
    def dlist = []
    for (def entry2 in depmap) {
        dlist.add(new java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry(entry2.key, entry2.value))
    }
    dlist
}
```

This has to be obviously called for each map you want to iterate, but the upside it, that the body of the loop stays the same.

```groovy
for (def e in mapToList(map))
{
    println "key = ${e.key}, value = ${e.value}"
}
```

You will have to approve the `SimpleImmutableEntry` constructor the first time, or quite possibly you could work around that by placing the mapToList function in the workflow library.

Comment: Found this post after an hour long battle with Jenkins. Having to go through this struggle to simple iterate over a native data structure is outrageous !

Comment: If you want to do anything complex, then its the first struggle of many. Apart from Groovy alone being a PITA (saving quotes depending on context, just so that you now need to learn when a name denotes a variable and when a string, after the scheme "outsmarted" your intention), they added some weird bugs on top and restrict almost anything from the base language. Then there are funny behaviours of the plugins (If you want to save an artifact and its missing, the pipeline just continues and fails at end).I wish I spent the time getting it somewhat working elsewhere... like setting up buildbot.

Comment: I used this solution but still get an error: "org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use new " (that's the new inside mapToList)

Comment: Yes, and that was addressed with the last sentence. Go to "Manage Jenkins" -> "In-process Script Approval" and apporve that method. Or ad a cript file in the [workflow-cps-global-lib](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin/blob/master/README.md), I haven' t testet it, but it shouldnt need approval there

Comment: Further tips on how to work with maps in groovy pipelines: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/docs/BEST_PRACTICES.md#groovy-gotchas

Comment: Most of the issues with iteration and binary closures should theoretically be handled now that [JENKINS-26481](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26481) is resolved.

Answer (score 15):

Or much simpler

```
for (def key in map.keySet()) {
  println "key = ${key}, value = ${map[key]}"
}
```

Comment: changing `for(def _environment in environments )` to `for (def _environmentKey in environments.keySet())` fixed the issue in Jenkins 2023 version. Thanks!!