# Lists and parallel tasks in a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, concurrency, jenkins-pipeline

I'm currently working on a Jenkins pipeline to provision different hosts using Ansible. Provisioning the different hosts would be done in parallel.

This is just a proof of concept to explore the possibility of doing it this way. So my method doesn't really do anything. This is it:def a

```
def ansibleSecurityTools(server){
    println("Clone Security Playbook")
    println("Download Ansible galaxy requirements")
    skipTags = []
    for (st in server.server.security_tools) {
        if (!st.value)
            skipTags.add(st.key.toLowerCase())
    }

    println(skipTags)
```

I create the parallel tasks like this:

```
securityTasks = env_config.servers.collectEntries {
    ["${it.server.hostname}_security_tools" : { ansibleSecurityTools(it) }]
}
```

And run them like this

```
parallel securityTasks
```

The tasks run in parallel, as expected. However, in the case of my sample data I was expecting to see 7 lists with `tripwire`. Nothing else. However, this is the console output:

```
Running on slave in /home/vagrant/jenkins/workspace/eac
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Parse Info from Server YAML)
[Pipeline] readYaml
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Run Terraform)
[Pipeline] echo
Placeholder
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Security Tools)
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] [HOST1_security_tools] { (Branch: HOST1_security_tools)
[Pipeline] [HOST2_security_tools] { (Branch: HOST2_security_tools)
[Pipeline] [HOST3_security_tools] { (Branch: HOST3_security_tools)
[Pipeline] [HOST4_security_tools] { (Branch: HOST4_security_tools)
[Pipeline] [HOST5_security_tools] { (Branch: HOST5_security_tools)
[Pipeline] [HOST6_security_tools] { (Branch: HOST6_security_tools)
[Pipeline] [HOST7_security_tools] { (Branch: HOST7_security_tools)
[Pipeline] [HOST1_security_tools] echo
[HOST1_security_tools] Clone Security Playbook
[Pipeline] [HOST1_security_tools] echo
[HOST1_security_tools] Download Ansible galaxy requirements
[Pipeline] [HOST2_security_tools] echo
[HOST2_security_tools] Clone Security Playbook
[Pipeline] [HOST2_security_tools] echo
[HOST2_security_tools] Download Ansible galaxy requirements
[Pipeline] [HOST3_security_tools] echo
[HOST3_security_tools] Clone Security Playbook
[Pipeline] [HOST3_security_tools] echo
[HOST3_security_tools] Download Ansible galaxy requirements
[Pipeline] [HOST4_security_tools] echo
[HOST4_security_tools] Clone Security Playbook
[Pipeline] [HOST4_security_tools] echo
[HOST4_security_tools] Download Ansible galaxy requirements
[Pipeline] [HOST5_security_tools] echo
[HOST5_security_tools] Clone Security Playbook
[Pipeline] [HOST5_security_tools] echo
[HOST5_security_tools] Download Ansible galaxy requirements
[Pipeline] [HOST6_security_tools] echo
[HOST6_security_tools] Clone Security Playbook
[Pipeline] [HOST6_security_tools] echo
[HOST6_security_tools] Download Ansible galaxy requirements
[Pipeline] [HOST7_security_tools] echo
[HOST7_security_tools] Clone Security Playbook
[Pipeline] [HOST7_security_tools] echo
[HOST7_security_tools] Download Ansible galaxy requirements
[Pipeline] [HOST1_security_tools] echo
[HOST1_security_tools] [tripwire]
[Pipeline] [HOST1_security_tools] }
[Pipeline] [HOST2_security_tools] echo
[HOST2_security_tools] [tripwire, tripwire]
[Pipeline] [HOST2_security_tools] }
[Pipeline] [HOST3_security_tools] echo
[HOST3_security_tools] [tripwire, tripwire, tripwire]
[Pipeline] [HOST3_security_tools] }
[Pipeline] [HOST4_security_tools] echo
[HOST4_security_tools] [tripwire, tripwire, tripwire, tripwire]
[Pipeline] [HOST4_security_tools] }
[Pipeline] [HOST5_security_tools] echo
[HOST5_security_tools] [tripwire, tripwire, tripwire, tripwire, tripwire]
[Pipeline] [HOST5_security_tools] }
[Pipeline] [HOST6_security_tools] echo
[HOST6_security_tools] [tripwire, tripwire, tripwire, tripwire, tripwire, tripwire]
[Pipeline] [HOST6_security_tools] }
[Pipeline] [HOST7_security_tools] echo
[HOST7_security_tools] [tripwire, tripwire, tripwire, tripwire, tripwire, tripwire, tripwire]
[Pipeline] [HOST7_security_tools] }
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

As you can see, it seems to be using the "same" list. However, if I add `sleep` (`val` is a random int <= 10)

```
def ansibleSecurityTools(server, val){
    println("Clone Security Playbook")
    sleep(val)
    println("Download Ansible galaxy requirements")
    skipTags = []
    for (st in server.server.security_tools) {
        if (!st.value)
            skipTags.add(st.key.toLowerCase())
    }

    println(skipTags)
}
```

The results change and prints are correct and some are not. These results change randomly with each execution.

For instance, this time I get what I expected in the first place.

```
Running on slave in /home/vagrant/jenkins/workspace/eac
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Parse Info from Server YAML)
[Pipeline] readYaml
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Run Terraform)
[Pipeline] echo
Placeholder
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Security Tools)
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] [HOST1_security_tools] { (Branch: HOST1_security_tools)
[Pipeline] [HOST2_security_tools] { (Branch: HOST2_security_tools)
[Pipeline] [HOST3_security_tools] { (Branch: HOST3_security_tools)
[Pipeline] [HOST4_security_tools] { (Branch: HOST4_security_tools)
[Pipeline] [HOST5_security_tools] { (Branch: HOST5_security_tools)
[Pipeline] [HOST6_security_tools] { (Branch: HOST6_security_tools)
[Pipeline] [HOST7_security_tools] { (Branch: HOST7_security_tools)
[Pipeline] [HOST1_security_tools] echo
[HOST1_security_tools] Clone Security Playbook
[Pipeline] [HOST1_security_tools] sleep
[HOST1_security_tools] Sleeping for 3 sec
[Pipeline] [HOST2_security_tools] echo
[HOST2_security_tools] Clone Security Playbook
[Pipeline] [HOST2_security_tools] sleep
[HOST2_security_tools] Sleeping for 5 sec
[Pipeline] [HOST3_security_tools] echo
[HOST3_security_tools] Clone Security Playbook
[Pipeline] [HOST3_security_tools] sleep
[HOST3_security_tools] Sleeping for 2 sec
[Pipeline] [HOST4_security_tools] echo
[HOST4_security_tools] Clone Security Playbook
[Pipeline] [HOST4_security_tools] sleep
[HOST4_security_tools] Sleeping for 9 sec
[Pipeline] [HOST5_security_tools] echo
[HOST5_security_tools] Clone Security Playbook
[Pipeline] [HOST5_security_tools] sleep
[HOST5_security_tools] Sleeping for 6 sec
[Pipeline] [HOST6_security_tools] echo
[HOST6_security_tools] Clone Security Playbook
[Pipeline] [HOST6_security_tools] sleep
[HOST6_security_tools] Sleeping for 8 sec
[Pipeline] [HOST7_security_tools] echo
[HOST7_security_tools] Clone Security Playbook
[Pipeline] [HOST7_security_tools] sleep
[HOST7_security_tools] Sleeping for 5 sec
[Pipeline] [HOST3_security_tools] echo
[HOST3_security_tools] Download Ansible galaxy requirements
[Pipeline] [HOST3_security_tools] echo
[HOST3_security_tools] [tripwire]
[Pipeline] [HOST3_security_tools] }

[Pipeline] [HOST1_security_tools] echo
[HOST1_security_tools] Download Ansible galaxy requirements
[Pipeline] [HOST1_security_tools] echo
[HOST1_security_tools] [tripwire]
[Pipeline] [HOST1_security_tools] }

[Pipeline] [HOST2_security_tools] echo
[HOST2_security_tools] Download Ansible galaxy requirements
[Pipeline] [HOST2_security_tools] echo
[HOST2_security_tools] [tripwire]
[Pipeline] [HOST2_security_tools] }
[Pipeline] [HOST7_security_tools] echo
[HOST7_security_tools] Download Ansible galaxy requirements
[Pipeline] [HOST7_security_tools] echo
[HOST7_security_tools] [tripwire]
[Pipeline] [HOST7_security_tools] }

[Pipeline] [HOST5_security_tools] echo
[HOST5_security_tools] Download Ansible galaxy requirements
[Pipeline] [HOST5_security_tools] echo
[HOST5_security_tools] [tripwire]
[Pipeline] [HOST5_security_tools] }

[Pipeline] [HOST6_security_tools] echo
[HOST6_security_tools] Download Ansible galaxy requirements
[Pipeline] [HOST6_security_tools] echo
[HOST6_security_tools] [tripwire]
[Pipeline] [HOST6_security_tools] }

[Pipeline] [HOST4_security_tools] echo
[HOST4_security_tools] Download Ansible galaxy requirements
[Pipeline] [HOST4_security_tools] echo
[HOST4_security_tools] [tripwire]
[Pipeline] [HOST4_security_tools] }
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

However, running the exact same thing again results in something different.

```
Running on slave in /home/vagrant/jenkins/workspace/eac
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Parse Info from Server YAML)
[Pipeline] readYaml
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Run Terraform)
[Pipeline] echo
Placeholder
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Security Tools)
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] [HOST1_security_tools] { (Branch: HOST1_security_tools)
[Pipeline] [HOST2_security_tools] { (Branch: HOST2_security_tools)
[Pipeline] [HOST3_security_tools] { (Branch: HOST3_security_tools)
[Pipeline] [HOST4_security_tools] { (Branch: HOST4_security_tools)
[Pipeline] [HOST5_security_tools] { (Branch: HOST5_security_tools)
[Pipeline] [HOST6_security_tools] { (Branch: HOST6_security_tools)
[Pipeline] [HOST7_security_tools] { (Branch: HOST7_security_tools)
[Pipeline] [HOST1_security_tools] echo
[HOST1_security_tools] Clone Security Playbook
[Pipeline] [HOST1_security_tools] sleep
[HOST1_security_tools] No need to sleep any longer
[Pipeline] [HOST2_security_tools] echo
[HOST2_security_tools] Clone Security Playbook
[Pipeline] [HOST2_security_tools] sleep
[HOST2_security_tools] Sleeping for 9 sec
[Pipeline] [HOST3_security_tools] echo
[HOST3_security_tools] Clone Security Playbook
[Pipeline] [HOST3_security_tools] sleep
[HOST3_security_tools] Sleeping for 9 sec
[Pipeline] [HOST4_security_tools] echo
[HOST4_security_tools] Clone Security Playbook
[Pipeline] [HOST4_security_tools] sleep
[HOST4_security_tools] Sleeping for 7 sec
[Pipeline] [HOST5_security_tools] echo
[HOST5_security_tools] Clone Security Playbook
[Pipeline] [HOST5_security_tools] sleep
[HOST5_security_tools] Sleeping for 3 sec
[Pipeline] [HOST6_security_tools] echo
[HOST6_security_tools] Clone Security Playbook
[Pipeline] [HOST6_security_tools] sleep
[HOST6_security_tools] Sleeping for 5 sec
[Pipeline] [HOST7_security_tools] echo
[HOST7_security_tools] Clone Security Playbook
[Pipeline] [HOST7_security_tools] sleep
[HOST7_security_tools] Sleeping for 3 sec
[Pipeline] [HOST1_security_tools] echo
[HOST1_security_tools] Download Ansible galaxy requirements
[Pipeline] [HOST1_security_tools] echo
[HOST1_security_tools] [tripwire]
[Pipeline] [HOST1_security_tools] }

[Pipeline] [HOST5_security_tools] echo
[HOST5_security_tools] Download Ansible galaxy requirements
[Pipeline] [HOST5_security_tools] echo
[HOST5_security_tools] [tripwire]
[Pipeline] [HOST5_security_tools] }
[Pipeline] [HOST7_security_tools] echo
[HOST7_security_tools] Download Ansible galaxy requirements
[Pipeline] [HOST7_security_tools] echo
[HOST7_security_tools] [tripwire]
[Pipeline] [HOST7_security_tools] }

[Pipeline] [HOST6_security_tools] echo
[HOST6_security_tools] Download Ansible galaxy requirements
[Pipeline] [HOST6_security_tools] echo
[HOST6_security_tools] [tripwire]
[Pipeline] [HOST6_security_tools] }

[Pipeline] [HOST4_security_tools] echo
[HOST4_security_tools] Download Ansible galaxy requirements
[Pipeline] [HOST4_security_tools] echo
[HOST4_security_tools] [tripwire]
[Pipeline] [HOST4_security_tools] }

[Pipeline] [HOST2_security_tools] echo
[HOST2_security_tools] Download Ansible galaxy requirements
[Pipeline] [HOST3_security_tools] echo
[HOST3_security_tools] Download Ansible galaxy requirements
[Pipeline] [HOST2_security_tools] echo
[HOST2_security_tools] [tripwire]
[Pipeline] [HOST2_security_tools] }
[Pipeline] [HOST3_security_tools] echo
[HOST3_security_tools] [tripwire, tripwire]
[Pipeline] [HOST3_security_tools] }
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Is there something related to Java/Groovy concurrenty or parallelism in Jenkins I might be missing here?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710342/iterating-jenkins-groovy-map-with-multiple-sets/51713574#51713574